# Swift 4 - Dealing with lots of data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I built a calculator whose results are predefined results, for example, if I type 1 + 2 the result will be 100.

for that cause I created a class called dataTemplate :

```
class DataTemplate {
var firstNum : Int
var secondNum : Int
var wantedResult : Int

init(firstNumber : Int, secondNumber : Int, theWantedResult : Int) {
    firstNum = firstNumber
    secondNum = secondNumber
    wantedResult = theWantedResult
}
```

}

and another class called "ResultsList"  with all of the combinations:

```
class ResultsList {

var list = [DataTemplate]()

init() {
    list.append(DataTemplate(firstNumber: 40, secondNumber: 1, theWantedResult: 39))
    list.append(DataTemplate(firstNumber: 40, secondNumber: 2, theWantedResult: 38))
    list.append(DataTemplate(firstNumber: 40, secondNumber: 3, theWantedResult: 37))
    list.append(DataTemplate(firstNumber: 40, secondNumber: 4, theWantedResult: 36))
    list.append(DataTemplate(firstNumber: 40, secondNumber: 5, theWantedResult: 35))
    list.append(DataTemplate(firstNumber: 40, secondNumber: 6, theWantedResult: 34))
   }
```

the "RestultsList" class contains all combinations, and it works great when there are something like 30 combinations, but for my usage, I need to put something like 1000 combinations, and that will make the code much much longer so in what way can I write all my combinations which is not in the xCode file ?

can I use something like a database?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you generate the data in code? For example, `theWantedResult` in your example is `firstNumber - secondNumber`

Comment: No it’s actually + , if you type 40 + 1 you get 39, all of the combinations’ results are gotten with add

Comment: @ZivAviv - Is there any logic to your combinations? The values you've shown are all  the result of subtracting the 2nd number from the 1st... but will you have just random combinations such as `firstNumber: 4, secondNumber: 3, theWantedResult: 21`?

Comment: @DonMag - you know what, I just figured out there is some logic (the app is for my brother) and I think it can be achieved with some calculation with the 2 numbers, so I think my problem is solved but now I have a different question, can I detect how long is the exercise? for example, how can I know if the user typed x + y + z and then hit = or just x + y ?

Comment: @ZivAviv - at the start of the exercise, save the current time in a variable. When the user types `=` subtract the saved time from the (new) current time.